# SceneKit iOS9 rendering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, sprite-kit, scenekit

I found an issue and i can't understand what is going on here.

I have a 2D-based game with 3D character.

2D-base is SpriteKit and 3D from the SceneKit through `SK3DNode`.

All works fine with iOS 10-11, but iOS 9 has an inexplicable behaviour. Some of triangles (i think half of them) of my 3D character are transparent.

**Let me show you example with Box.**

I have a *.dae (Collada) model exported from the Blender's start scene it's looks like a usual Box.

Then i have some code to show it on my UIViewController with different render viewports (`SCNView` and `SKView`):

```objective-c
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SKView *skView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SCNView *scnView;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SCNScene *boxScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"Models.scnassets/box_default.dae"];

    // SceneKit
    {
        self.scnView.scene = boxScene;
        self.scnView.backgroundColor = [SCNColor magentaColor];
    }

    // SpriteKit
    {
        SKScene *skScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:self.skView.frame.size];
        skScene.backgroundColor = [SKColor magentaColor];

        SK3DNode *skNode = [SK3DNode nodeWithViewportSize:self.skView.frame.size];
        skNode.scnScene = boxScene;
        skNode.position = CGPointMake(skScene.size.width / 2, skScene.size.height / 2);
        [skScene addChild:skNode];

        [self.skView presentScene:skScene];
    }
}

@end
```

[Result image with Preview and different ios/device screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMMJW.png)

Now I have 2 questions:

- why i can't see some triangles of Box sides on iOS 9?
- why colors looks different on iOS 11?

I tried to change render option for `SKView` and tried different options for export .dae from the Blender and i can't got same result for different iOS and viewports.

I'm using:

- XCode 9.0 (9A235)
- Blender 2.78c
- iPhone 4S iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
- iPhone 5S iOS 11.0 (15A372)

What can i do here?

Comment: SpriteKit is terribly broken on iOS 9. It worked very well on iOS 8, works OK on iOS 10, haven't tried it on iOS 11 yet. Maybe a suggestion is to develop for min iOS 10?

Comment: What i can say? It is a perfect... Apple code support said that this is a bug and asks to provide more details about it with bug-report.

Comment: Not sure why they would have you file a report if it is working on 10 and 11.  They are not going to release an update patch to iOS 9 lol

Comment: Yes it is funny but it is. They ask me to check is it working normal on current version of iOS+XCode but anyway provide an information about this behavior as a bug-report =]